# Storing polynomials as is from the from poly1D() function into a list

Tags: python, list, numpy, polynomials

I want to store the polynomials into a list but when I append them into the list they lose the variable x and just have the coefficients.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
from pylab import *
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

np.random.seed(2)
pageSpeeds = np.random.normal(3.0, 1.0, 1000)

# purchaseAmount function (non-linear)
purchaseAmount = np.random.normal(50.0, 10.0, 1000) / pageSpeeds

x = np.array(pageSpeeds)
y = np.array(purchaseAmount)

polyfitInit = {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0, 10:0, 11:0, 12:0, 13:0, 14:0, 15:0}
polyforms = []
for c in polyfitInit:
    z = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, c))
    r2 = r2_score(y, z(x))
    polyfitInit[c] = r2
    polyforms.append(z)

print polyforms
```

Ouptut now:

[poly1d([ -9.04306562,  46.68709008]), poly1d([  3.73263241, -31.78596189,  77.53159067]...]

Output wanted: 
[-9.043 x + 46.69,  3.73263241x^2 + -31.78596189x + 77.53159067...]

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

`poly1d` makes a object of this class.

```
In [153]: p = np.poly1d([1,2,3])
In [156]: type(p)
Out[156]: numpy.lib.polynomial.poly1d
```

The `repr` of this class is the string that you got; the `str` is the string that  you want

```
In [159]: repr(p)
Out[159]: 'poly1d([1, 2, 3])'
In [160]: str(p)
Out[160]: '   2\n1 x + 2 x + 3'
In [161]: print(p)
   2
1 x + 2 x + 3
```

Put several of these in a list, your `polyforms`

```
In [162]: alist = [p, p]
In [163]: alist
Out[163]: [poly1d([1, 2, 3]), poly1d([1, 2, 3])]
In [164]: print(alist)
[poly1d([1, 2, 3]), poly1d([1, 2, 3])]
```

Print of the list displays the `repr` form, not the `str`.

There's a distinction between the display strings and the actual objects.  My `alist` is a list of actual `poly1d` objects.  It isn't a list of their string representation(s). The variable `x` isn't part of the `poly1d` object.

The key attribute or data of a `poly1d` is its `coef`

```
In [165]: p.coef
Out[165]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

And you can perform an evaluation on each element of the list:

```
In [172]: [q(.5) for q in alist]
Out[172]: [4.25, 4.25]
```